# Store http request data in synchronised queue and execute one by one in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, firebase-cloud-messaging, queue, message-queue

I am creating fcm device token storing application in spring boot.

Where I get fcm token data from frondend site.

Currently using redis message broker and storing tokens in queue.

But as fas as my understanding is concerned queue is async.

I don't want server MySQL load to be high to execute all token storing parallel.

So please suggest me technology aur the method by which I can store my token synchronously in database.

For example

If we have 3 webs

Web1
Web2
Web3

I want to store token of all of three in synchronised  manner ..

Note:- order doesn't matter for me

Answer (score 0):

why you are not trying REST API or GRAPHQL for this action?
GRAPHQL is a better choice

Comment: What is the use case of graphql here ?